# Plane equation exercise

Tags: plane-geometry

.Find the plane equation that contains the X axis and the point A(4,-3,-1)
The correct answer is y-3z=0 
Anyone could explain me why is that the answer and is not -3y-1z=0? 
Thanks you in advanced! 
Sorry for my English, I'm Spanish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will suffice to find two linearly independent points in the plane. One such point is the unit vector in the $x$-direction. That would be $(1,0,0)$. Another is the point $(4,-3,-1)$. Go ahead and take their cross-product to produce a vector normal to the plane. You know that each vector in this plane is then orthogonal to the normal vector. Can you get the equation for the plane from that?

Comment: Sorry,What is cross product?

Comment: @Ceco The cross-product of $(a,b,c)$ with $(d,e,f)$, written $(a,b,c)\times(d,e,f) = (bf - ce, cd - af, ae - bd).$

Comment: I could do it but the answer is y-3z=0 and i optein y+3z=0 :( thanks for answer

Comment: @Ceco, I computed the cross product and determined the vector $(0,1,-3)$ as being normal to the plane. Check your calculation. With this in hand, do you see how to get the equation of the plane?